# How to run individual test method in Android Studio v0.5.2

Tags: android, junit, android-studio, automated-tests, android-gradle-plugin

In Android Studio v0.4.2 I was able to right click on individual *methods* within my test classes and run a single automated test.  After updating to v0.5.2 I can't do that any more.

When I upgraded to v0.5.2, it automatically updated me to the v0.9 Gradle plugin.  I had to follow [the migration instructions](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating_to_09), which included renaming "instrumentTest" to "androidTest".

Before this update, I was able to right click on individual methods within a test class and run them individually.  After the update, the default option is to `Run 'MyProject - App Engine DevAppServer`, which doesn't apply to my project, so it doesn't run the test.

[image: run individual test method]

Does anybody know how to change that default so my tests run individually?  Some of my tests extend the simple JUnit `TestCase`, but most of them extend `AndroidTestCase`.  At the moment both are treated as App Engine tests.

Right clicking and running an entire test class still works completely fine.

[image: run test class]

I'm running Mac OS X 10.9.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to Android Studio v0.5.8 (or greater - I'm now seeing that v0.5.9 is available for download) via "Help->Check for update".

I can right-click and run an individual test method within a class on Android Studio v0.5.8 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64bit:

[image]

The above class is from the [OneBusAway Android project on Github](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android), if you want to try with this project and eliminate your project/source as the cause of the issue.

Here are my full Android Studio / JDK details:

[image]

Comment: I reproduced the problem on v0.4.2 using the OneBusAway project, and confirmed that upgrading to v0.5.9 solved it.  Thanks!